# Impala-Hbase JOIN query running slow

Tags: sql, hadoop, hbase, hdfs, impala

I'm currently using Impala to query data in Hbase and join another Impala HDFS table. The query is very slow. The query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM impala_hdfs_table a
JOIN impala_hbase_table b
ON a.index = b.index
where a.month =9;
```

`index` is the row key in Hbase table. I would expect that this query will directly access to the specific row in HBase(since I provide the row key), and join the result with `impala_hdfs_table`. But impala explained the plan like this with a FULL scan in Hbase:

```
Estimated Per-Host Requirements: Memory=1.00GB VCores=2

05:EXCHANGE [UNPARTITIONED]
|
02:HASH JOIN [INNER JOIN, PARTITIONED]
|  hash predicates: b.index = a.index
|
|--04:EXCHANGE [HASH(a.index)]
|  |
|  00:SCAN HDFS [inspex.impala_hdfs_table a]
|     partitions=1/13 files=1 size=11.63MB
|
03:EXCHANGE [HASH(b.index)]
|
01:SCAN HBASE [inspex.impala_hbase_table b]
```

So right now the query is running very slow. My question is: **How does Impala translate Impala query into HBase? Is there a way to run a query like this so that we can avoid FULL scan in Hbase?** Thanks.

PS: The reason why I combine HDFS and Hbase is that, our use case requires some UPDATE operations for several columns, So I split out those and create a helper table in HBase to maintain that part of data.

And the column in Impala mapping to row key in hbase is String. Both `index` in two tables are string. The reason why I did this is Hbase rowkey must be mapping to a String column(See [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_hbase.html)). Otherwise there is will be a full scan.

Comment: did you create index on those tables? How slow is very slow? Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Wait what?  you have a string being compared to a (numeric?) and then filtered based on a numeric.  a.index is a string? Why?  The implicit conversion casting is costing you.  Shoudln't the FK (index) in hdfs also be of the same data type as hbase.index?  Seems odd that it wouldn't be.

Comment: @xQbert No both `index` in two tables are string. The reason why I did this is Hbase rowkey must be mapping to a String column(See [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_hbase.html)). Otherwise there is will be a full scan. So as you said the two index are in same data type and there is no casting issue.

Comment: Other than `AND b.index = 1006` should be `AND b.index = '1006'` you mean.

Comment: @xQbert I will correct that thx